# how to take keyEvent on eclipse platform

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, editor, keylistener

i was making an application for editor on eclipse plugin and using Eclipse PDE with "Hello,World Command" template.
The application works, after running the program, it run eclipse platform with sample menu. 
How to take keylistener when user type on running eclipse platform editor ?

Comment: This is rather unclear. Are you opening an editor? Which one? Why do you want to listen to key events? There may be a better way of doing what you want. [edit] your question and provide a lot more detail.

Comment: @greg-449 okay sorry for detail, I want to compare between two codes based on key event (for plagiarism).  so the user, type codes in editor (that I build from eclipse plugin)  then the editor catch the key whenever the user type on the editor. is this more clearer? thx (sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an editor extending `TextEditor` you can get the underlying `StyledText` control using:

```
StyleText styled = getSourceViewer().getTextWidget();
```

You can then call `addKeyListener` to add a key listener (there is also `addModifyListener`). The Source Viewer also has `addTextListener`.